# How to scroll screen within screen with the outer screen keybindings?

Tags: gnu-screen, remote, terminal-emulator, scrolling

I run a screen session locally on my laptop.  Within that screen session, I connect via ssh to a server on which I do most of my work.  Since that connection gets reset sometimes (e.g. VPN timing out), I run a screen session on the server as well so that I can reconnect to it and have my shell exactly as it was.

So my workflow is: wake laptop, switch to terminal, find local screen session running but a message showing connection timed out, ssh to my server, run `screen -x` to reconnect to the screen session on the server, and do my work.

The `~/.screenrc` file on the server just contains one line, `altscreen on`.  Otherwise all my custom screen stuff (including customizing the meta-character to be Ctrl-Space, and having a status bar with window names) is on my laptop only.  (I also have `altscreen on` in my laptop's `.screenrc` file.)

The upshot of this is that I can control the remote screen session using Ctrl-A (the default) and I can control the local screen session using Ctrl-Space.  I don't normally control the remote screen session or do anything with it except connect to it—but that's where my question comes in.

Currently, if I try to scroll back on the remote server using Ctrl-Space+[, it doesn't work correctly.  I may see the contents of previous Vim buffers I had open, or other stuff.  To scroll back on the remote server, I **have** to use Ctrl-A+[.

**How can I make it so I can scroll normally, i.e. using Ctrl-Space+[, and see the proper scrollback history for my shell on the remote server?**  In other words, I want to pretend that `screen` doesn't even exist on the remote server, since I want to use it ONLY for purposes of resuming my work where I left off before the connection was interrupted.

Comment: Why do you have a screen on the laptop?

Comment: @MaxMuster muscle memory for tab switching and scrollback copying.  I could use iTerm tabs for separate tabs (i.e. a separate GUI tab for each shell/server I'm logging into), but I like having it all in screen.  Also, unfortunately, I cannot ssh to all servers I need to from that main working server, so I have to ssh directly from my laptop for some things.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you will never want to use Ctrl-Space+\[ for your local screen session? In other words, are you prepared to sacrifice that keybinding and make it work *only* with the remote screen?

Answer (score 1):

`screen` is a terminal emulator within another terminal. You can scroll back OK in the outer screen but if the application you run in it is something like `screen` or `vim` or another semi-graphic application which implements its screen rendering including scrolling by itself, and not using the terminal (here `screen`) scroll buffer, then there's nothing that terminal (here `screen`) can do about it.

It's the same thing if you run `screen` within `xterm` for instance. You can't use `xterm`'s scrollbar anymore.

You'll notice that when you reattach the remote screen, you see the contents of the remote `screen` terminal screen and you get access to *its* scrollback buffer (by interacting with *that* `screen`).